# C, Calculating the distance between two GPS locations?

Tags: c, gps, coordinates, distance, haversine

If I have two GPS locations, say 51.507222, -0.1275 and 48.856667, 2.350833, what formula could I use to calculate the distance between the two? I've heard a lot about a haversine formula, but can't find any information about it, or how to apply it to C.

I've written the following code, however, it's very innacurate. Anybody know why? I can't figure it out. The problem comes from the function itself, but I don't know what it is.

```
float calcDistance(float A, float B, float C, float D) 
{
    float dLat;
    float dLon;
    dLat = (C - A);
    dLon = (D - B);
    dLat /= 57.29577951;
    dLon /= 57.29577951; 
    float v_a;
    float v_c;
    float distance;

    v_a = sin(dLat/2) * sin(dLat/2) + cos(A) * cos(C) * sin(dLon/2) * sin(dLon/2);
    v_c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(v_a),sqrt(1-v_a));
    distance = r * v_c;
    return distance;
}
```

Comment: `float` is a rather bad choice for the type of parameters, local variables and the function itself. Use `double` instead. In the absence of a **strong** reason to use `float` (or `long double` in C99) use `double`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) has a block of Javascript which I'm sure you could adapt easily enough in C:

```
var R = 6371e3; // metres
var φ1 = lat1.toRadians();
var φ2 = lat2.toRadians();
var Δφ = (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
var Δλ = (lon2-lon1).toRadians();

var a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
        Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
        Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

var d = R * c;
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is absolutely correct.

I would rename parameters `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` to `lat1`, `lon1`, `lat2` and `lon2`.

It returns the distance in kilometers.  You need to define `r` as 6371, roughly the [radius of the earth](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=radius%20of%20the%20earth).

Comment: Thanks, that's why I was off.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the [great circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance).

Comment: Thanks, but for someone who isn't hugely savy in math, this is really complicated. I'll try and figure it out.

Comment: What, you don't expect people to tunnel through the Earth's crust to reach the destination? :)

Comment: I've used what I have been able to learn, and tried to make a simple function. It's up in the above post. Why's it not working?

Answer (score 1):

Maybee its too late, but this is the reason of the inaccurate calculation:
-> A and C (lat1 and lat2) must also be converted from degree to radians

```
dLat /= 57.295779513082325;
dLon /= 57.295779513082325;
lat1 /= 57.295779513082325;
lat2 /= 57.295779513082325;
```

regards,
omeier