# How to calculate approxiamtely by default Approx 60 miles in yii

Tags: yii

How to calculate approximately by default  Approx 60 miles using lat and lng

in yii.

```
$criteria->with = array('merchant');
    $criteria->select = '*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(' . $latitude . ') ) 
            * cos( radians( merchant.lat ) ) * cos( radians( merchant.lng ) - 
            radians(' . $longitude . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $latitude . ') ) 
            * sin( radians(  merchant.lat ) ) ) ) * 1.609344 AS distance'; 
    $criteria->having=("distance < 4");
```

Its not working properly.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C, Calculating the distance between two GPS locations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838481/c-calculating-the-distance-between-two-gps-locations)

Answer (score 0):

MSQL statement that will find the closest 20 locations that are within a radius of 25 miles to the 37, -122 coordinate.

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?hl=en